# Python map where users can add locations?

Tags: python, maps, google-maps

I'm trying to make a website where users can add points to a map. The map would be populated with points by users clicking on the map and adding a title and description to the latitude/longitude point. Anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Geodjango is a good start - it consists of geospatial extensions to the popular Python Django web framework.

The actual map will be displayed with something like Leaflet.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Leaflet API](https://leafletjs.com/) might work for what you are wanting to do.